# Invalid base64-encoded string when trying to upload BufferedReader to Azure Blob Storage in Python

Tags: python, csv, bufferedreader, azure-blob-storage

When trying to upload CSVS in a folder to the blob it throws in the first CSV:

Exception:
Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (85) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

Thanks!

```
import os 
import io 
import glob from base64 
import b64decode, b64encode 
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient 
path = "D:/Git projects/csvs" 
extension = 'csv' 
os.chdir(path) #gets files that are from TODAY only 
result = glob.glob("*"+ str(today) + ".{}".format(extension))

try: 
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str) 
     for csv_file in result: # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob 
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=, blob=blob_name) # Upload the created file 
        with open(csv_file, "rb") as data: 
            #data = data.read().decode("utf-8") 
            #data = data.encode("utf-8") 
            blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite = True) 
except Exception as ex: 
    print('Exception:') 
    print(ex)`


OUTPUT: Exception: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (85) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
```

Comment: import os
import io
import glob
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient

path = "D:/Git projects/csvs"
extension = 'csv'
os.chdir(path)
#gets files that are from TODAY only
result = glob.glob("*"+ str(today) + ".{}".format(extension))

Comment: try:
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    for csv_file in result:
        # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=, blob=blob_name)

        # Upload the created file
        with open(csv_file, "rb") as data:
            #data = data.read().decode("utf-8")
            #data = data.encode("utf-8")
            blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite = True)
except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)

Comment: OUTPUT:

Exception:
Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (85) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

Comment: I had a similar issue. It was related with the credentials that where being passed in the wrong format. Please have a look at my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71129515/azure-datalake-python-error-invalid-base64-encoded-string-number-of-data-chara/71129516#71129516

Answer (score 0):

You can check the encoding of the csv data you are trying to upload :

```
import chardet
with open(csv_file,"rb") as data
chardet.detect(data)
```

The output of chardet will be something like :

```
{'encoding': 'EUC-JP', 'confidence': 0.99}
```

The libary to detect encoding is : https://github.com/chardet/chardet . Then you can work on converting that encoding and try to upload again