# Azure Datalake python error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (85) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

Tags: python, azure, csv, azure-data-lake

When trying to upload CSV in a folder to the datalake blob, i get an error message related with base64 encoding. The csv is a string format and seems correct.

I have tried encoding the csv many ways and nothing seems to work.

```
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(
                                                account_url=datalake_url,
                                                credential="supersecret")
    
unstable_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="my_container")
    

    
    def store_remote_csv(   base_path: str, 
                            mega_csv: Optional[str], 
                            table_name: str,
                            unstable_system_client: FileSystemClient):
        file_path = f"{base_path}{table_name}"
        try:
            logger.info(f"Uploading csv to the datalake")
            unstable_system_client.create_file(file=file_path)
            output_file = unstable_system_client.get_file_client(file_path=file_path)
            output_file.upload_data(mega_csv, overwrite=True)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Failure {e}.") 

store_remote_csv("/base/", pd.read_csv("some.csv").to_csv(), "table_name",  unstable_system_client )

OUTPUT: Failure: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (85) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the credentials.

```
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(
                                                account_url=datalake_url,
                                                credential="supersecret")
```

credential should be a type ClientSecretCredential (from azure.identity) and NOT string.

```
from azure.identity import ClientCredential    
client_secret_credential = ClientSecretCredential(
                                                        tenant_id=datalake_tenant_id,
                                                        client_id=datalake_client_id,
                                                        client_secret=datalake_client_secret)
    service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(
                                            account_url=datalake_url,
                                            credential=client_secret_credential)
```

He is essentially trying to decode the string into and object.